# Software to add images to video?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor

I have a video where I want to put images on my hand (in the video) and have them fly all over the video screen. Is there any software for Ubuntu 11.10 to do this or at least to insert an image into the video in a custom position?

Answer (score 5):

**[kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/features)** is more like a video editor which supports lots of audio/video/images formats, including mpg, flv, ogg, jpg, mp3, avi, wav, etc.

It is more like Sony Vegas in Windows and it allows you to merge between file formats/sources, this way you can put an image with transparency over a running video, change original audio and include effects, transitions, pan, zoom, crop, and other video effects. Color correction is also supported and it works project based, which allows you to create full scenes in a project and insert projects in a final project without rendering.

Some screenshots of my desktop are provided here to illustrate what you want to do: I am placing a png with transparency image over a video, zooming and positioning over the video.

[image]
*Here we can see the media tracks, a video and a png image.*

[image]
*In this screenshot I am using pan and zoom plugin in order to resize and position the png over the video.*

[image]
*And we are using the composition video transition all over the png image's duration in order to place it over the video.*

BTW: Pan and Zoom and other interesting plugins/video effects supports automation, which is useful for your desired *"to put images on my hand (in the video) and have them fly all over the video"*

A video editor is what I suggest you for this task, any of them are fine but if you are used to Movie Maker, Sony Vegas, Adobe Premiere, and these kind of software, you will feel comfortable when using kdenlive.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

***FfDiaporama,*** (Windows equivilent - Pro-Show Gold) is an application for assembling photos and videos. It is inspired by presentation software such as Impress or Powerpoint . It can read all image formats, a majority of cameras and camcorder video formats, and the most commonly used music formats.

It includes 140 transitions and a device database for the generation of videos with more than 50 models of video viewing devices (including smartphones, tablets, and home cinema systems). ffDiaporama can manage several hundreds of slides. Every slide can contain several tens of shots and several tens of blocks. Every shot contains its own block settings. The application calculates all the shot transformations.

[Check it out Here](http://ffdiaporama.tuxfamily.org/)

[***Openshot Video Editor***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenShot_Video_Editor) is something else you might want to consider, but it a bit more basic