# How do I correctly install ffDiaporama (slideshow software) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, dependencies, video-editor, slideshow

**Background**

I had some issues with dependencies etc and I thought it would be useful if I posted the correct solution here so other community members could benefit.  I am not sure it appropriate to do this on AU but there are a lot of high profiles sites out there giving incomplete information. (This caused me some issues)

> Note :ffDiaporama is an open source application for creating video
>   sequences consisting of titles, fixed or animated, images or photos,
>   fixed or animated, movie clips & music.

**Related Question on AU**
[Software to add images to video?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124800/software-to-add-images-to-video)

**Similar Open Source Software**
[Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/features), 
[Openshot](http://www.openshot.org/), 
[Kino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kino_%28software%29)

Comment: This is not only OK but is appreciated. Until you are doing it inside the scope of the site *(not too narrow)* or It's already discussed, and get solved in the same mannar *(in that case, it is a duplicate)*. This is IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before building ffDiaporama, make sure you that you have all the necessary packages for compiling and running it.

You need to have the Medibuntu repository enabled for the ffmpeg lib

> [Click here](http://medibuntu.org/repository.php) to learn how to activate the Medibuntu repository

**Copy and Paste the following code into Terminal, then enter your password**

```
 sudo apt-get install libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqt4-network \
 libavcodec-extra-53  libavformat-extra-53 libavdevice-extra-53 \
 libswscale-extra-2 ffmpeg  build-essential libqt4-dev qt4-dev-tools \
 libavutil-dev libavformat-dev  libavcodec-dev libswscale-dev \
 libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev  libexiv2-11 libexiv2-dev \
 libtag1-vanilla libtag1-dev
```

Download and Install the .Deb file [from here](http://ffdiaporama.tuxfamily.org/?page_id=178)

That’s it!